# Runnable interface and Thread class not imported. Why?

Tags: java

I was learning about concurrency from the Oracle's Java Tutorials and I tried the following two examples in my local machine-

```
public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new Thread(new HelloRunnable())).start();
    }

}
```

and

```
public class HelloThread extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new HelloThread()).start();
    }

}
```

The examples worked. Now, Pardon me if the question seems very kiddish, as I am a novice in Java's programming, but why wasn't the `Runnable` interface, in first example, and  `Thread` class, in both examples, imported?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Classes and interfaces of the java.lang package are imported by default.

Comment: Each class which is in java.lang package is automatically imported into each class. Those two classes Runnalble and Thread are part of it. See java doc's:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html and 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others stated, classes and interfaces inside java.lang package are not required to be imported. They are imported by default.

You can check some examples in this website. None of the java.lang classes are imported:

[java.lang examples](http://www.java-tips.org/java-lang.html)

But also note that classes/interfaces in sub-packages have to be imported (check reflection examples on that page).

Answer (score 1):

Runnable and Thread belong to java.lang package. Interfaces and classes from this package are implicit. They are not required to be imported.